# How to convert 2d nested array into 2d array single?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array `a` as follow : `[[(0,0),(2,0)],[(1,1)], [(3,8)]]`

So now I want to convert it like this: `[(0,0),(2,0),(1,1), (3,8)]`

How may I do that?

I had tried bellow code and successed, but I need some ideas better and faster.

```
nresult = []
for i in range(len(result)):
    arr = result[i]
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        nresult.append(arr[j])
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The term you are looking for is *flatten* of a list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` from `functools` like this

```
from functools import reduce

a = [[(0,0),(2,0)],[(1,1)], [(3,8)]]
res = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,a)

print(res) # [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1), (3, 8)]
```

Comment: Happy to hear I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your nested-deep is certain, you can use **chain** from **itertools** package

```py
from itertools import chain

data = [[(0,0),(2,0)],[(1,1)], [(3,8)]]

result = list(chain(*data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions -

```
nested = [[(0,0),(2,0)],[(1,1)], [(3,8)]]
un_nested = [inside_element for element in nested for inside_element in element]
# Returns - [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1), (3, 8)]
```